# EC2 application to access database server whitelist ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, whitelist

On my EC2 instance, I need to create an application (PHP) that accesses a database on a server that whitelists IPs

I have a little admin experience and what I think this means for the PHP app to access the external database is "outbound" traffic?

If so, I believe the outbound IP is not static for EC2 and I think I would then need to create a NAT Instance and VPC?  Then provide the NAT "static" IP to the database server Admin so it can be added to their whitelist?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

An Amazon EC2 instance can be assigned a **Public IP address**. There are two types:

- A Public IP address that is **randomly assigned** when an instance is started. If the instance is later Stopped and Started, this address might change, *or*
- An **Elastic IP address** that is a static IP address that can be assigned to an EC2 instance. The instance will keep that address even when stopped/started, until the Elastic IP address is removed from the instance.

Based on your description, an Elastic IP address would be appropriate for adding to a whitelist.

A **NAT Instance or NAT Gateway** is primarily used to grant Internet access to resources that are in a private subnet, since they (intentionally) lack direct connectivity to the Internet. They also use an Elastic IP address to obtain a static address.

Comment: Thanks John!  One thing I forgot to mention is this EC2 also hosts my dev web server.  Can I use this for both with the Elastic IP (web server and php app) ?  I suspect so since as you mention the Elastic IP creates a static IP.
Also, when I created the Elastic IP and associated it with my instance, an option was to select a Private IP in the dropdown.  Should I select the Private IP?  Finally, after the Elastic IP was created I couldn't reach my instance when entering the public IP.  Sorry, just new to this and still learning how this work.  Thanks again

Comment: Correct. When assigning an Elastic IP address, it replaces the existing "random" IP address -- you will need to reconnect. The Elastic IP address "maps" to a private IP address. In fact, all traffic from the Elastic IP address (or Public IP address) enters the instance through the private IP address. This makes it easy to move the Elastic IP address to another instance without changing any configuration inside the actual instance. The Elastic IP address will point to your instance for both incoming requests to your web server and outgoing requests to the database.

Comment: I created the Elastic IP address, selected the Private Ip from the downdown  and associated it with my EC2 instance. I rebooted the instance and the Elastic IP  and Public IPs are now the same. The strange thing is when I try to go the new Public IP it redirects to another IP and get msg "this site can't be reached".  

Any idea?

Comment: There was no need to reboot. The assignment of an Elastic IP address is immediate. The IP address will be going to your instance, so whatever is happening is a result of whatever is being served from the web server on your instance. To prove this, you can Stop your instance then try again -- you should find that it times-out because no server can be reached.

Comment: John, my bad.  The elastic ip worked perfectly !(as you knew it would).  This is a dev server for our Mangento app.  I forgot to update Magento with the new static ip.  All is good now.  Thanks for your help!